# Changing the axes box default line width

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Due to page limitations, I have to shrink many of my plots. While shrinking, the plot box's line thickness also appear thinner on paper.

I can control default line thickness of plot lines using

```
set(0,'Defaultlinelinewidth',2)
```

in the startup file. However, this does not influence the thickness of the box line. Each time, I have to do `set(gca,'linewidth',2)` for every plots manually. Is there a way to change the box line default thickness (from the current default of 0.5 to 2) permanently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the default **`line`** property `LineWidth` *not* the default `LineWidth` value for the `axes` (`Default**line**linewidth`). Instead you will want to use the following to set the default `LineWidth` for `axes` objects.

```
set(0, 'DefaultAxesLineWidth', 2)
```

You can include this in your [`startup.m` file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) if you'd like that to be set as the default every time that you launch MATLAB.

In general, the formula for default property names is:

```
'Default<object_type><property_name>'
```